# Mysql - How to query a row from table _a that is link to table_b pointing to a different a row in table_a

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**For Example:**

***table_a***

```
table_a
|key|Value|
|---|-----|
| 2 |john |
|---|-----|
| 3 |james|
-----------
```

and **table_b**

```
table_b
|key|key2 |
|---|-----|
| 2 |3    |
|---|-----|
| 9 |5    |
-----------
```

**Output:**

```
desired_tbl
|key|Value|
|---|-----|
| 2 |james|
-----------
```

Its like a self referencing table but in a **very different** way...
I hope you can help me. **thank you.**.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT a1.key, a2.value 
FROM table_a as a1, table_b as b, table_a as a2
WHERE a1.key = b.key
AND b.key2 = a2.key;`

- [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f581c/24)

Comment: After having our company devotional, I was able to figure out the answer.. and yes your answer is right.. but in my part I use join.. thanks..